# Webflow form not submitting to hubspot

Tags: hubspot, webflow

I have a Webflow form that I have confirmed is submitting as I can see the submission data in the site settings.

I am connecting this form to Hubspot with the integration and using the "Map Webflow form to Hubspot form" option. I am able to successfully map the form but when I submit I'm not seeing anything submitted to Hubspot.

Let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help. I'm new to both of these apps so hoping someone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! In the Hubspot form I made all of the fields optional vs required and now everything submits!